# How to revert to windows if JS value is null

Tags: javascript

I have like no JS experience, but I need help.

So I have a code that allows a user to manually enter a URL.

Well, If they leave the value blank and click out it "NULLS". I want a way to detect that null and revert back to "/" or the same page instead of /null

```js
function url(){
    swal("Enter a URL:", {
        content: "input",
      })
      .then((value) => {
        location.replace(value);
        
      });
}
// PROD Fix, needs a zero-null failure-fix. Find a way to prevent zero-data/null.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a test for the null value before the location.replace() and change the value to the url you want as default.

```
function url(){
    swal("Enter a URL:", {
        content: "input",
      })
      .then((value) => {
        if (value === null) value = "your replacement url";
        location.replace(value);
        
      });
}
```

Comment: Godspeed, this worked and I can add onto the expression you provided.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with the check `if (value === null)` if you can receive either null or an empty string. The condition will fail, if you receive an empty string.

I would use `if (!value)` instead to cover both null && "".